# Extension v2 for Dynamics NAV 2017

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I got used to develop Extensions for Navision based von V2, so I was wondering, if there is a way to use the AL-Dev-Tools for developing V2 Extensions for Dynamics NAV 2017.

I could not find the **ALLanguage.vsi** for *Version 10*, 
only for *Version 11* (NAV 2018) and *Version 12* (NAV BC).

Is there a way to get a ALLanguage.vsi for Dynamics NAV 2017 or do I have to undust the old Dynamics DevEnviroment?

Thanks for helping,
greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
And Extensions V2 is supported only from NAV2018 onwards
Regarding the vsix, you can find it in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central\130\AL Development Environment\ it's the ALLanguage.vsix
You can install it in Viscose using "Install from VSIX"

Comment: Well, I think there will be no other way than going back to Extension V1, right? Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, it depends. I wouldn't recommend it but if you need to solve this w/ an extension yes

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make extensions for anything other than NAV 2018 and BC

Comment: Thank you very much. But there is a difference between Extension V1 and V2. So it is possible to write Extensions for NAV 2017, but only V1 Extensions...